# Li-Yau inequality on $\mathbb R^2$ for functions that are somewhat close to $1$

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, heat-equation

Let $u:\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R_{>0}\to \mathbb R_{>0}$ be a positive solution to the heat equation on $\mathbb R^2$ ($u_{xx}+u_{yy}=u_t$, no constants). The Li-Yau inequality in this case states that
$$
\Delta w\geq -\frac{1}{t},
$$
where $w=\ln u$. This inequality is known to be optimal, because the identity is attained by the heat kernel $U(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi t}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{4t}\right)$. The heat kernel, however, goes to $0$ quite fast as $x^2+y^2$ grows. So, my question is

1. Assume that for small $t$ and large $x^2+y^2$ we know that our solution is (on average) close to 1. Can we improve the bound in terms of $t$? For example, I know that for $R\geq \sqrt{1/t}$ we have something like
   $$
   \int_{x^2+y^2\leq R^2}(u(x,y,t)-1)^2dxdy=O\left(\frac{R\ln R}{\sqrt t}\right).
   $$
   I am interested in the case when $t$ is very close to $0$.
2. Can the bound at least be improved on average? I.e. what can be said about
   $$
   \int_{x^2+y^2\leq R^2}\Delta w(x,y,t)dxdy
   $$
   under the same assumptions as above?